# How to switch class float left and right in a css according to direction changes?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I have a sidebar menu and it should float left or right according to page direction , I made a solution with a custom rtl-style.css but in my case i should use only 1 style sheet (style.css).

```
#sidebar.active { left: 0;}  in ltr 
#sidebar.active { right: 0;} in rtl
```

Comment: can you share the entire nav HTML and CSS (or layout structure) to demonstrate your issue and clarify about *direction changes*. Is it about the language direction (dir/direction/unicode-bidi/else... )? There could  be very simple ways to deal with that. But what's your case alike?

Answer (score 2):

Direct css solution is available only in Firefox so far (Oct 2019) and it uses [:dir() CSS pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:dir) this way:

```
#sidebar.active:dir(ltr) { left: 0;}
#sidebar.active:dir(rtl) { right: 0;}
```

Support table [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-dir-pseudo).

For all other browsers, best way is to add a body class depending on text direction. So, once you have:

```
<body class="text-rtl">
```

... than later on you can in one stylesheet place:

```
#sidebar.active { left: 0;}
.text-rtl #sidebar.active { right: 0;}
```

That's it.

Comment: body[dir="rtl"] .page-title {
    text-align: right!important;
}

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help , actually  I adjust my code (in the same stylesheet) as the following and it saved my day :

```css
#sidebar.active
{
left : 0;
}
body[dir="rtl"] #sidebar.active
 {
   right:0!important;
 }
```

Comment: This will only work if the body has a `dir` attribute (i.e. css `direction` won't work, for example)